# How to store variables from an input text file?

Tags: java

StackOverflow I am a CS student who is having trouble on an assignment who needs someone to assist me with this assignment. The assignment has me take a input file which has data that looks like this:

```
FirstNameFXO|LastFXO|2510 Main Street|Suite 101D|City100|GA|72249|$280.80
FirstNamePNR|LastPNR|396 Main Street|Suite 100A|City102|GA|24501|$346.01
FirstNameXZU|LastXZU|2585 Main Street|Suite 107C|City101|GA|21285|$859.40
FirstNameHWD|LastHWD|1019 Main Street|Suite 102D|City105|GA|28273|$317.12
FirstNameGHP|LastGHP|2097 Main Street|Suite 109B|City106|GA|72621|$279.28
FirstNameUKM|LastUKM|1087 Main Street|Suite 109C|City106|GA|81463|$711.91
FirstNameKUV|LastKUV|2685 Main Street|Suite 106B|City102|GA|37141|$951.47
FirstNameTBO|LastTBO|1971 Main Street|Suite 103C|City101|GA|63018|$851.35
```

There are 1000 lines, I am trying to take this data and create an output file that would be laid out like a letter but the problem I am having is I do not know how to take each individual part of the input so I could have a value that I could use like this:

output.write("Dear" + firstName + lastName, but I do not know how to make them variables. I have created an array that takes each individual line but I am stuck here. Any assistance would be amazing. I am very new to File I/O in general so this is very challenging for me.

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CollectionLetter {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            File file = new File("dataCollection.txt");
            String data[] = new String[1000];
            try {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
                while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
                        data[i] = s.nextLine();
                    }
                    System.out.println(data[1]);
                }s.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to store values from a a text file but it outputting incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982158/trying-to-store-values-from-a-a-text-file-but-it-outputting-incorrectly)

Answer (score 1):

`String` has a method `split(String)` which, well, splits a string and returns its parts as an array.
For every line you could do:

```
final String[] parts = line.split("|");
```

Which gives you an array of length 8 (given that every line is structured the same way). Now depending on how you want the individual parts to look like you may want to use methods like `substring(int)` or `substring(int, int)` which return only a part of the string (e.g. to cut out "FirstName").